# Images Not Showing Up in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a background to my website with a canvas. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uXJMA/. The gradient is showing up, but the repeating image is not. Can anyone help me figure out why the image isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original --------- this doesn't answer the question

Honestly I know very little about canvas, but assuming the image you are adding looks like static, try adding     document.body.appendChild(canvas);

http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/sWYHM/

never saw that object being added to the DOM, so it's worth a try?

---

Revised

What you need is -webkit-canvas(mycanvas);

there's an example here:
http://www.webkit.org/blog/176/css-canvas-drawing/

I made a working version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/vwRyt/

Comment: yep, that's what I was about to say.

Comment: That will show the canvas but not as the "background" really for the `<body>`.  I guess it could be absolutely positioned, but if the page is resized it won't adapt. (Then again, if it's to repeat when it's the background image, it's not clear why there's any point to showing the image via the canvas anyway!)

Comment: true, missed that in the op's question.  Could you do something like set the z-index to an absurdly negative number and hack it?

Comment: Edited my answer to be (what I think is correct), left the original comment so Pointy's comment made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You need to put the canvas on the page inside the image "onload" handler. Currently you're doing it before the image is loaded. The  handler won't be called until after your code that sets up the background runs, in other words.
2. Even if you do that, however, it won't work because the browser will consider it a security error to access the bits of an image fetched from a different domain.

Comment: The image is actually local. I just uploaded it so it would work on jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah.  Well if the image is in your domain, then it will (probably) work.  Just put that code that comes after the point at which you set the image source *inside* the "onload" handler.